# Checking at runtime if a class has a specific constructor that is using generics

Tags: java, generics, reflection, constructor, introspection

Hello all :) I'm trying to chose the right constructor in a class. Here is the code:

```
Constructor[] constructors = targetClass.getConstructors();
Constructor goodConstructor = null;
for (Constructor constructor : constructors) {
    Class[] parameterTypes = constructor.getParameterTypes();
    if (parameterTypes.length = 1 && parameterTypes[0].equals(Map.class)) {//here
        goodConstructor = constructor;
    }
}
```

I want to switch from `Map.class` to `Map<String, String>.class`. I vaguely remember that generics are for compile time only, so this is why the compiler is complaining. How can I check at runtime that the class has the right constructor?

Best regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use `getGenericParameterTypes()` instead:

```
public class FindConstructor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        for (Constructor<?> constructor : MyClass.class.getConstructors()) {
            Type[] parameterTypes = constructor.getGenericParameterTypes();
            if (parameterTypes.length == 1 && parameterTypes[0] instanceof ParameterizedType) {
                ParameterizedType parameterizedArg = (ParameterizedType) parameterTypes[0];
                if (parameterizedArg.getRawType() != Map.class) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (parameterizedArg.getActualTypeArguments()[0] != String.class) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (parameterizedArg.getActualTypeArguments()[1] != String.class) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("found constructor " + constructor);
        }
    }
}

class MyClass {
    public MyClass(Map<String, String> map) {
    }
}
```

Now if you change `MyClass()` to take a `Map<String, Integer>` it will no longer match.

This becomes much easier with Guava's [`TypeToken`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html), which utilizes an anonymous class to create a parameterized `Type` that we can compare to.

```
Type mapStringString = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
for (Constructor<?> constructor : MyClass.class.getConstructors()) {
    Type[] parameterTypes = constructor.getGenericParameterTypes();
    if (parameterTypes.length == 1 && parameterTypes[0].equals(mapStringString)) {
        System.out.println("found constructor " + constructor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Removed my answer; I should be more careful before replying with the stock "generics use type erasure" answer! I would say that if you are doing this then there is almost certainly something wrong with your design though! :)

Answer (score 0):

Classes do not work that way in java. Classes cannot be parameterized at runtime; only instances. There is only one `Map.class`, rather than (as you seem to have assumed) a separate class for every generic implementation of Map. The following code might help to clarify this:

```
    Map<String,String> m1 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Object,Long> m2 = new HashMap<>();

    System.out.println(m1.getClass() == m2.getClass());//prints "true"
```

Comment: While this is true of `Class`, Java does have support for representing a type which has type parameters, namely `ParameterizedType` (see my answer).  Type parameters are quite often compiled in (any time you declare a generic field or parameter, for starters).  If that information wasn't available in the class file, you wouldn't be able to compile against a class that uses generics.